# How to use @Autowired in subclass for field defined in base class?

Tags: spring, interface, abstract-class, subclass, autowired

Is it possible to autowire an instance in a subclass for a field which is fdefined in the base class?

So,
The interface:

```
public interface Xyz { ...}
```

The abstract base class:

```
public abstract class Abc {
    Xyz xyz;
}
```

The subclass(es) of the absctract class where I want to autowire a concrete implementation of the interface:

```
public class Def extend Abc {
    @Autowired
    // Here I want to autowire a concrete implementation of Xyz, maybe called XyzImpl. Can I do this maybe in a constructor or ...?
}

public class Ghi extend Abc {
    @Autowired
    // Here I want to autowire a concrete implementation of Xyz, maybe called XyzImpl. Can I do this maybe in a constructor or ...?
}

public class Jkl extend Abc {
    @Autowired
    // Here I want to autowire a concrete implementation of Xyz, maybe called XyzImpl. Can I do this maybe in a constructor or ...?
}
```

Comment: Did you try it to see the result?

Comment: Do you have exactly one bean that implements Xyz or is it ambiguous? You can stick the `@Autowired` on the instance of xyz in `Abc` otherwise and it'll work out fine. I do this all the time. (Alternatively you can do constructor injection.)

Comment: No, I have ambigious classes implementing the interface.

Comment: How do you expect it to know which Xyz to inject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. In the `Abc` class, make this change `private final Xyz xyz;`
2. In the `Abc` class, add a constructor that takes an `Xyz` parameter; set the `xyz` field in this constructor.
3. in the `Def` class, add a constructor that takes an `Xyz` parameter and which calls `super(xyz)`.
4. Autowire the `xyz` parameter in the `Def` constructor.